# Why I get different result from Observable

Tags: angular, rxjs

When I load the page and make the request at first `(this.userService.getAllUsers$)` as a response, I get an array of objects, but if I reload the page I get a single object. If I call only `this.userService.getAllUsers$` and subscribe to it, everything is okay. When the route is changed, everything also is okay. It works incorrectly only if I reload the page several times, the problem appears only after about the fifth reload.

```
public ngAfterViewInit(): void {
        if (!this.article) {
            this.articleSubscription = this.route.paramMap
                .pipe(
                    switchMap(params => {
                        this.isLoadingInProgress = true;
                        return this.dataService.getArticleById(params.get('id')).pipe(
                            flatMap(response => {
                                this.article = response.currentArticle;
                                this.article.relatedArticles = response.relatedArticles;

                                return this.userService.getAllUsers$();
                            }),
                        );
                    }),
                ).subscribe(users => {
                    console.log(users);
                    const author: AlArticleAuthor =
                        users.find(user => user.id === this.article.userId);
                    this.article.author = {
                        firstName: author.firstName,
                        lastName: author.lastName,
                    };
                    this.isLoadingInProgress = false;
                    super.setTitle(this.article.title);
                    super.setMetaDescription(this.article.description);
                    this.changeDetection.markForCheck();
                });

        }
}
```

}

```
public getAllUsers$(): Observable<ALUser[]> {
    return this.storeService.collectionValueChanges<ALUser>('users');

public collectionValueChanges<T>(path: string): Observable<T[]> {
    return this.getEnvDb().collection<T>(path).valueChanges();
}
```

Comment: show the logic inside getAllUsers$ function

Comment: I tried to use only  getAllUsers$ in AfterViewInit without other request, everything work correct

Comment: try changing "switchMap" and "flatMap" to mergeMap

Comment: unfortunately, it doesn't help

Comment: What do you mean by reloading, like `F5` hard refresh? Also what is `collectionValueChanges` is it possible something to write value inside this collection when you are reloading the page and this loading to cause some race condition, that is being triggered from time to time?